# Problems to send a list from view to controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller, send

I have problems to send a list from view to controller in MVC.

This is the code in view:

```
foreach (var c in ViewBag.Categories)
{
  <a href="@Url.Action("SubCategory", "Product", new { selected = selected, id = @c.Item.ID, category = @c.Item.Name })" id="link" class="list-group-item">
   <span> @c.Item.Name</span>
  </a>
// { TempData["Childrens"] = c.Children; }
```

}

The ViewBag.Categories contains a Children list for each item, as you can see in the attached screenshot:
  [image]

This is the code in controller:

```
public ActionResult SubCategory(string selected, int id, string category)
{
        var childrens = TempData["Childrens"] as IEnumerable<Helpers.TreeItem<Categories>>;
        var listOfChildrens = childrens.ToList();

  }
```

I need that children list in the ActionResult parameter list, something like this:

```
 public ActionResult SubCategory(string selected, int id, string category, **childrens**)
{
```

Can you please advice me how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you using TempData in Controller and in View you're using ViewBag?

Comment: The TempData was just for test

Comment: why don't you create **viewmodel** for this which contains selected,id,category and categorylist and than pass it to view instead of using viewbag

Comment: @Orsi Can you check the answer and tell me If that solve your problem or not ?

Comment: Sure, I'll check and I'll come back with an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Curiousdev Why would he? Both methods work, they didn't implement the ViewBag for nothing.

Comment: @Arendax yes i agreed both methods will work but i don't recommend this one.

Answer (score 0):

Add what you want from Form in a Model and submit this model and You must render `Childrens` in your view as `Hidden fields` so when you submit `Controller` can match them.

```
public Class MyModel {
   public string selected {get;set;} 
   public int id {get;set;} 
   public string category {get;set;} 
   public List<Children> childrens {get;set;}
}



for (int i= 0; i< Model.Categories.Count; i++)
{
   ....
   @Html.HiddenFor(x=> Model.childrens[i].Yourproperty1)
   @Html.HiddenFor(x=> Model.childrens[i].Yourproperty2)
   .... 
}
```

If you don't want to create a Model and keep dealing with Viewbag, still possible but you have to pass to controller all properties you need from childrens with the same `name` as HiddenFileds if you don't want to show it in your form

> You need to change this code according to your business and your
>   properties but it just for presenting my idea.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: I made the viewmodel as you have suggested, and now I'm passing a list to the view. Can you please advise in one more question. What would be the best way to send hidden fields to the controller?

Comment: @Orsi If you add these fields in your form and submit the form, it will send to Controller
`public ActionResult SubCategory(MyModel model)`

Comment: I added in a new answer my questions

Comment: I tried as you have suggested with sending the model to the controller, but the model is always null. I pasted the code in the answer. Do you have any ideea what is the problem?